# Changing onClick to be random

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to make the handler OnClick to just be random instance instead of requiring user interaction.

```
// add the canvas in
  document.body.appendChild(mainCanvas);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', createFirework, true);
  document.addEventListener('touchend', createFirework, true);

// and now we set off
    update();
  }

  /**
   * Pass through function to create a
   * new firework on touch / click
   */
  function createFirework() {
        createParticle();
  }
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: something like window.setInterval(createFirework, 1000) will cause the "click" handler to trigger once a second. Is that similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: You want to call `createFirework` at random intervals? If so, what should the shortest, and longest, interval be?

Comment: Jonathan Sampson: Yes, that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @syazdani Yes! That's what I believe I'm looking for. Now where do I place that and how do I set the interval to be random?

Answer (score 0):

Having a function call itself isn't too difficult:

```
// This function executes itself the first time immediately
(function randFunc () {
    // We output some information to the console
    console.log("Called myself..." + new Date());
    // And then instruct this function to be called between 0 and 10 seconds
    setTimeout(randFunc, Math.random() * 10 * 1000);
}());​​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8tZEu/2/

Comment: Now, I'm a JS N00B. Where do I place this?

Comment: @user1932995 Anywhere... unless it requires other environmental variables to already be setup, or the DOM to be loaded.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this :( Would it be like this?

(function createFirework () {
    createParticle());
    setTimeout(randFunc, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 * 1000));
}());​

Comment: @monospaced Your call to `setTimeout` should include a reference to the function you want to call. You still have `randFunc`, even though you changed the name of that function to `createFirework`. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just extend a good solution from Jonathan: you do not need to create eventListeners the recursive randFunc() is  invoked at random times until you quit the browser.

I Guess you need to implement a way to stop the function. Here is one solution:

```
     var stopFW = false;
        function randFunc () {
             // stop execution           
            if (stopFW) return;
            console.log("Called myself..." + new Date());
            // And then instruct this function to be called between 0 and 10 seconds
            setTimeout(randFunc, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) * 1000);
        }

        function stopFireWork() {
            stopFW = !(stopFW);
            console.log(stopFW);
        }

<body onload="randFunc()">    
    <button onclick="stopFireWork()">Stop Firework</button>
</body>
```